# implement alphabetical scroll in MPMediaPickerController app

Tags: iphone, scroll, alphabetical, mpmediapickercontroller

If you go to the iphone library and then go to songs, you will see the songs being displayed in a similar way to the MPMediaItemPicker class does. The only difference is that the ipod application shows the search bar right at the top of the list and also a nice alphabetical scroll on the right hand side whereas the MPMediaItemPicker class only isplays a simple scroll going up and down.
How can i implement an alphabetical scroll on the right in the MPMediaItemPicker class?
Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this code:

https://github.com/jaminguy/JGMediaPicker

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you cannot customize the MPMediaPickerController yourself beyond of course what is stated in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008221).

You will need to implement your own picker, using media queries (by song ,by artist, etc).

I suggest reading: [“Using the iPod Library”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingTheiPodLibrary/UsingTheiPodLibrary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH101-SW1) in Apple's "iPod Library Access Programming Guide"