# Albhabetic scrollbar and multiple selection in MPMediaPickerController

Tags: iphone, mpmediapickercontroller

I would like to have both the alphabetic scrollbar (which appers when multiple selection is disabled) and the multiple selection enabled in my MPMediaPickerController. Any thoughts???

Answer (score 0):

I answered similar question recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570991/implement-alphabetical-scroll-in-mpmediapickercontroller-app/6484422#6484422)

As far as i know you cannot customize the MPMediaPickerController yourself beyond of course what is stated in the documentation.

You will need to implement your own picker, using media queries (by song ,by artist, etc).

I suggest reading: “Using the iPod Library” in Apple's "iPod Library Access Programming Guide"